# Ticks issue for ListLogPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks

**Bug introduced in 12.1 or earlier and fixed in 13.0.0**

---

Consider the following plot (Mathematica 12.1):

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{x, x^-10}, {x, 1, 5}], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True]
```

There is a problem with ticks - the ticks on the left side do not coincide with the ticks on the right side of the plot:
[image]

Could you please tell me how to fix them to be as on the left side?

Comment: Hmm. What version? On 11.2, this is not a problem. Could you try - `Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic}`?

Comment: @e.doroskevic Thanks, I've updated the question (Mathematica 12.1). The proposed solution does not work.

Comment: I upvote. Hopefully, somebody comes around to offer help. I am afraid, I cannot test a solution, given the difference in version. Perhaps, you could precompute ticks and impose them in `Frame` specification. The specification is `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` and you can use `Automatic` and `All` as valid input.

Comment: Works in version 13.0

Comment: Works in version 12.0 (Win10-64)

Comment: Shows different ticks in 12.2.0 on Win7. Can you apply custom-defined ticks or do you need help with that? Now that you mention it, I notice that the docs have more examples of such behavior.

Comment: produced on MMA 12.3 Win10. 64

Comment: produced on MMA12.3.1 on Ubuntu18.04

Comment: I reproduce the problem with version 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 13.0.0. So it seems the bug is fixed in version 13.0.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Version 12.1.1 also has mismatched [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) on the left and right edges:

```
llp = ListLogPlot[
  Table[{x, x^-10}, {x, 1, 5}],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Looking at the `FrameTicks` option values:

```
Cases[llp, HoldPattern[FrameTicks -> ft_] :> ft, Infinity]

(* {{{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
   Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}}} *)
```

Setting both left and right to Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}] will put them in agreement; however, the tick labels also will show up on the right. Use [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) to hide the labels on the right.

```
ListLogPlot[
 Table[{x, x^-10}, {x, 1, 5}],
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}],
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Scaled[0.001]}, 
  {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As recommended by Carl Woll, to avoid the need to change the `ImagePadding` use

```
Show[
 ListLogPlot[
  Table[{x, x^-10}, {x, 1, 5}],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True], 
 FrameTicks -> {
  {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
   Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, 
  {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use ``Show[graphic, FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]`` instead of hiding the labels with ImagePadding.

Comment: @CarlWoll - Thanks, I incorporated your comment.